# Programmatically get the default log generated from a SpecRun tests

Tags: specflow

When I run my SpecRun tests, it generates a log of the execution and places it in my *TestResults* directory. How might I programmatically get the full name of the log that is dynamically generated during a test run?  In my BeforeTest hook I am deleting all files in the TestResults directory, and I would like to exclude the current log for the test run.  Is this the right hook to do this in?  I may select to run 20 tests at once, and I am hoping that the files, previous to the 1st test out of the 20 tests, are being removed only once. After that, no need to delete files after another test that is ran.  So If I multi-select to run 20 tests, remove files from the directory as a precondition before the tests are ran.

Comment: What is the reason, that you want to delete the files in the TestResults directory? The files from a previous run should not influence an later run.

Comment: Considering I will be running these tests quite frequently through builds, the directory gets rather large with files. I just want to remove files previous to the latest test run

Comment: Do you know how this can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be, to exclude the logfile from deleting.

The format of the filename of the logfile is the following: %ProjectName%_%Name%_%Timestamp%.log

%ProjectName%: value from Settings/projectName from the used srProfile file.
%Name%: value from the Settings/name or the filename of the used srProfile file.
%Timestamp%: DateTime.Now with "s"- format string - ':' are removed

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow+/SpecRun.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. i will try this